# For Emacs, how to store what view-lossage collects into an external file?

Tags: emacs, elisp, keylogger

For Emacs, how do I store what `view-lossage` collects into an external file?  Ideally I'd like to store these keystroke data into an external log file incrementally and automatically, meaning it is done so by default when Emacs is started.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Emacs 24 at least (I can't check a prior version right now), the docstring for `view-lossage` states:

> Display last 300 input keystrokes.
>
> To record all your input on a file, use `open-dribble-file'.

And <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `open-dribble-file` <kbd>RET</kbd> tells me:

> open-dribble-file is an interactive built-in function in `C source
>   code'.
>
> (open-dribble-file FILE)
>
> Start writing all keyboard characters to a dribble file called FILE.
>   If FILE is nil, close any open dribble file.
>   The file will be closed when Emacs exits.

So simply add something like the following to your .emacs file:

```lisp
(open-dribble-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lossage.txt"))
```

Experimentally this clobbers the file if it already exists, so you'll need to deal with that.

Here's one approach. It accounts for multiple Emacs sessions by using `make-temp-name` to generate a semi-random filename for the dribble file, and then appends the contents of that to a primary lossage log file when Emacs exists. (If Emacs crashes, it would leave behind the temp file for you to deal with manually.)

```el
(defmacro my-persistent-dribble-file (file)
  "Append the dribble-file for this session to persistent lossage log FILE."
  `(let* ((persistent-file (expand-file-name ,file))
          (temporary-file (make-temp-name (concat persistent-file "-")))
          (persistent-arg (shell-quote-argument persistent-file))
          (temporary-arg (shell-quote-argument temporary-file))
          (append-dribble-command (format
                                   "cat %s >>%s && rm %s"
                                   temporary-arg persistent-arg temporary-arg)))
     (open-dribble-file temporary-file)
     (eval `(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
                      (lambda () (shell-command ,append-dribble-command))))))

(my-persistent-dribble-file "~/.emacs.d/lossage")
```

Comment: This stores lots of strings `<help-echo>` in the log file.  Any idea what are those?

Comment: Search for `help-echo` in here: `M-: (info "(elisp) Misc Events") RET`. FYI I found that simply by going to the elisp manual and using the index: `C-h i g (elisp) RET I help-echo RET` (you can also use the menus).

Comment: An easier way to deal with a unique filename is to use a timestamp:

`(open-dribble-file (expand-file-name (format-time-string "~/.emacs.d/%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M.txt")))`

Comment: pmielke: I have to disagree with you: (a) timestamps (especially with only per-minute granularity, as in your example) are not always unique; (b) creating unique filenames is the purpose of `make-temp-name`; (c) I don't think your code is "easier". That said, I think a timestamp-based approach is fine in this instance, provided the granularity is per-second (otherwise you're not sufficiently well protected against over-writing that file), as it saves you checking the creation date of the file if you end up with remnants of a crash. You could also combine the methods (timestamp + temp-name).

Comment: My use of `make-temp-name` *was* flawed in that I wasn't passing an absolute prefix path argument, though. An absolute path enables Emacs to guarantee uniqueness by verifying that the generated name doesn't exist. I've just fixed that.

Comment: That is a very cool technique. Has anyone been able to analyze it? or what would you use to read the lossage.txt file?