# How to log all of command I used in Emacs?

Tags: logging, emacs, key-bindings

Is there a way to do that. I'll use the log to make my best key-bindings.

Comment: Did you want the keys you pressed, or the commands that were run by the keys? For example, did you want `<C-f>` in the log, or `forward-char`? The prior is something which emacs calls "lossage", and can be viewed with `C-h l`. To save this data, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761401/for-emacs-how-to-store-what-view-lossage-collects-into-an-externel-file . If you want to store the functions you call, that's something I'm not sure about offhand.

Comment: I think both is the best. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an interesting article about ErgoEmacs: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/command-frequency.html

In «how the report is compiled», we learn about `keyfreq.el` to see how many times we used a command: https://github.com/dacap/keyfreq (available in ELPA: `M-x install-package RET keyfreq`).

Comment: Wow It save me a lot of time(word counting, ranking). Thanks

Comment: That Ergoemacs link has moved to http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/command-frequency.html

Answer (score 8):

In vanilla emacs you view the log of keys typed using `C-h l`. You may also want take a look at [command-log-mode](https://github.com/lewang/command-log-mode) which logs the keys typed as well as the corresponding commands.